# Sum up columns in MVC C# Razor View

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am wondering if I can sum up decimal in  all the columns that are dynamically generated in razor view without having to change this in controller and viewModel.  I will be happy to try jQuery option as well.

**ViewModel**

```
 public class LedgerViewModel
    {

    public LedgerViewModel(int PayCategoryCount)
    {
        PayCollection = new List<decimal>(new decimal[PayCategoryCount]);
    }
public DateTime PDate  { get; set; }


public class MonthlyPaymentsVM
{   public int PayCategoryId { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMMM yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> PaymentCategories { get; set; }
    public List<LedgerViewModel> Payments { get; set; }
    public List<LedgerViewModel> Member { get; set; }
}
```

**controller**

```
public ActionResult Report(int year, int no, string nom, Guid gcode)
        {
            DateTime startdate = (new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 7, 1));
            DateTime enddate = (new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 7, 1));
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

            //get all payments
            var a = from of in db.OfflinePayMents.Include(i => i.Customer).Include(i => i.PaymentCategory).ToList().Where(x => x.PDate >= startdate && x.PDate < enddate && x.POK && x.CustomerGuid=gcode) select new { of.Customer, of.PaymentCategory, of.CustomerID, of.PaymentCategoryID, of.PDate, of.TxnId, of.Pay, of.PType };

            var grouped = a.GroupBy(x => new { customer = x.CustomerID, PaymentCategory = x.PaymentCategory.PaymentCategoryID, txn = x.TxnId, pd = x.PDate, x.PType }).Select(x => new
            {
                Name = x.First().Customer.Name,
                Customer = x.First().Customer,
                PaymentCategory = x.First().PaymentCategory,
                Txn = x.First().TxnId,
                Pd = x.First().PDate,
                PType = x.First().PType,
                cid = x.First().PaymentCategoryID,
                Pay= x.Sum(y => y.Pay)

            });

            var data = grouped.GroupBy(x => x.Txn);
            var PaymentCategories = db.PaymentCategories.OrderBy(z => z.Order);
            var PayCategoryCount = PaymentCategories.Count();
            var PaymentCategoryIDs = PaymentCategories.Select(x => x.PaymentCategoryID).ToList();

            var model = new MonthlyPaymentsVM()
            {
                //Member = members,
                Date = date,
                PaymentCategories = PaymentCategories.Select(z => z.PaymentCategoryTitle),
                Payments = new List<LedgerViewModel>()
            };

            foreach (var group in data)
            {
                LedgerViewModel payment = new LedgerViewModel(PaymentCategoryCount);
                var pd = group.First().Pd;
                payment.PDate = pd;
                foreach (var item in group)
                {
                    int index = PaymentCategoryIDs.IndexOf(item.PaymentCategory.PaymentCategoryID);
                    if (index < 0)
                    {

                        payment.PayCollection[index + 1] = item.Pay;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        payment.PayCollection[index] = item.Pay;
                    }
                    payment.Total += item.Pay;
                }
                model.Payments.Add(payment);

            }


            return View(model);
        }
```

**Razor View**

```
<table class="doubleborder" width="99%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    @foreach (var payname in Model.PaymentCategories)
                    {
                        <th>@payname</th>
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Payments)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.PayDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</td>

                        @foreach (var amount in item.PayCollection)
                        {
                            <td>@amount.ToString("c")</td>
                        }



                    </tr>
                }
     <tr class="doubleborder">
     <td>Total:</td>
      @foreach (var item in Model.PaymentCategories)
      {
      <td>
looking at getting sum totals of each column here
      </td>
    }

    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

So this groups by customer. The payments are grouped by transaction Date and are iterated in the foreach loop in the view.

Thanks if you are able to help.

Comment: Maybe you could use the linq `.Sum()` method. i.e. `@payments.Select(x => x.amount).Sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your model correctly, this is what you are looking for:

```
@Model.Payments.Sum(i => i.Paycollection.Sum(x => x.amount));
```

**Update, based on your comment:** (and assuming that all the columns have value for all the PaymentCollections)

```
@for(int i = 0 ; i < PaymentCategories.Count(); i++)
{
    <td>
        Model.Payments.Sum(x => x.PayCollection[i]); //this will throw an exception if the value at index is not defined
    </td>
}
```

Comment: @Model.Payments.Sum(i => i.Paycollection.Sum(x => x)) this is what fits there without error but it puts the total sum of all the columns together

Comment: Ok, I've got it now, take a look at my update in the answer

Comment: still getting errors. the x.amount is not set in model so cannot get values

Comment: Could you share your Model class(es)?

Comment: It is a viewmodel and other models a lot of stuff to put up What is happening is  the payments are grouped by  date and they are displayed  sequentially in the order of  payment categories.  So am thinking solution will involve using indexing and maybe a for loop

Comment: I have added controller and viewmodels

Comment: Ok, now it is clear why you are getting the "amount not set" error. There is no amount elesewhere in your code (I don't know why your question contains that word, but we assume that it was part of your models, or maybe we've confused by your "amount" variable declared in the view's foreach). I think you missed some parts when pasted the models, but I can infer what you want. Take a look at my answer, I'll change a bit the **UPDATED** part

Comment: What it does is it add up  all payments in a row but not column as I need - I have 8 payment categories per date in  a row

Comment: Ok, Diin, I think I finally understand what you are trying to do. Try my last edit in the UPDATE section.